# Windows Task Scheduler, Scheduled Task begins despite "Start Task Only if computer is idle for" setting

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I am attempting to Schedule a task on a Windows 11 machine to run a log off user script after the computer has been idle for a certain duration.
I set the trigger to "on idle" and set "start the task only if the computer is idle for:" 30 minutes (pic attached)

Surprisingly, the computer runs the script as soon as the screen turns off (10 minutes).
I tested this by setting the screen to turn off after 1 minute and the task executes immediately.
From my understanding, this means the script is executing as soon as going into idle rather than when the idle duration condition is satisfied.

Any help understanding why I am seeing this behavior and/or tips to get my desired behavior would be much appreciated!

[image]